# Getting data from an uploaded file in Rails

Tags: file, ruby-on-rails-4, upload, get

I'm trying to get the original_filename and other stuff from an uploaded file.

The code in the view looks like:

```
<%= form_for(@datafile, url: user_data_files_path) do |f| %>

    <%= f.file_field :data%>

    <%= f.submit "Upload file", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

the params value in the debug console are:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",

 "authenticity_token"=>"Z4suAyN3zOpz1qBKllaDs3L4flz6Rm6HnN0CIdJvmcE=",

 "data_file"=>{"data"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007ff46b74e390 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/gf/lft827zj55b5wdj3208vpsy40000gn/T/RackMultipart20130803-635-q6wtb6>,

 @original_filename="application.html.erb",

 @content_type="application/octet-stream",

 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data_file[data]\"; filename=\"application.html.erb\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n">},

 "commit"=>"Upload file",

 "user_id"=>"1"}
```

I'm trying to retrieve things like original_filename and data, in my controller I have:

```
  def create

    @datafile = DataFile.new

    uploaded_io = params[:data_file]

    flash[:error]= '' + uploaded_io[:@original_filename]


    redirect_to new_user_data_file_url
  end
```

but I get an error: `no implicit conversion of nil into String` in the `flash[:error]` line.
I have tried to acces via:

```
uploaded_io[:original_filename]
```

that gives me the same error, or

```
uploaded_io.original_filename
```

and I get `NoMethodError`
The weird thing I see is that `flash[:error]= '' + uploaded_io.to_s` gives me the data_file hash, so.. I don`t understand what is happening.

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that the error was in thinking that `params[:data_file]` contained the file. The file is in `params[:data_file][:data]` (look at the view's form) and then that file has the method (variable instance) original_filename. So doing `params[:data_file][:data].original_filename` returns the file's name.